# There seems (to be) a... vs. There seems (to be) little

Tags: be, existential-constructions, to-be-deletion

> 1. *There seems to be a problem.*
> 2. *There seems a problem.*

In this type of construction, the version with *to be*, such as (1), is much more productive than the one without, such as (2). See this Ngram: [There seems to be a,There seems a](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=There%20seems%20to%20be%20a%2CThere%20seems%20a&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThere%20seems%20to%20be%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThere%20seems%20a%3B%2Cc0)

> 3. *There seems to be little doubt that....*
> 4. *There seems little doubt that....*

In this similar construction with "little", however, the version with *to be*, such as (3), is even less productive than the one without, such as (4). See this Ngram: [There seems little,There seems to be little](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=There%20seems%20little%2CThere%20seems%20to%20be%20little&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThere%20seems%20little%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThere%20seems%20to%20be%20little%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CThere%20seems%20little%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThere%20seems%20to%20be%20little%3B%2Cc0)

Would there be any logical explanation of this apparently counter-intuitive usage data?

Comment: Round about 2 million hits in both Google searches for "there seems to be little" and "there seems little" show currency. But productivity here surely refers to the number of different X's that will fill the slots "there seems [to be] little X ....", not directly addressed by the second two ngrams. // But I'd agree that _to-be_-deletion is rarely (ie not for many sensible NPs etc) available in strings of the form << There seems to be DetP/NP ... >>. Especially with NPs. << There seems reasonable ground to assume ...>> (even here, one could argue that 'reasonable' has quantifier force).

Comment: _There seems to be a problem_ is a fixed phrase and does not grammatically undergo _To be_-Deletion. See ["To be and not to be"](https://www.ingentaconnect.com/contentone/cls/pcls/1973/00000009/00000001/art00005?crawler=true&mimetype=application/pdf) for details on the rule.

Comment: @Greybeard Are you sure that the cited book discusses the issue raised in the OP? The linked portion doesn't seem to be particularly relevant. If I'm mistaken and you've read the book, please write up an answer even if it acknowledges that there's no logical explanation of the phenomenon.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for the paper, but the paper doesn't seem to discuss the existential _there_ construction at all.

Comment: @JK2 - I think you're right. I misdirected myself: it seems [to be] irrelevant.

Comment: @JK2 The paper discusses the constraints on _to be_-deletion, not _there_-insertion, which has its own constraints.

Comment: Are you sure "There seems a problem" is grammatical? I don't find it so ...

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. It's just an example of the construction, some being possible but less likely than the _to be_ version (e.g., _There seems a possibility..._) and others being virtually impossible (e.g., _There seems a problem._). I have intentionally chose the latter to bring out the contrast the most between the first and second pair.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out what you're asking, but these aren't complete sentences, and the difference is clearly not in _seems_ or _to be_. Let's have some data and stop waving hands.

Comment: *Doubt* can be either a countable or an uncountable noun — *problem* cannot. In your example, *doubt* is uncountable. The use of *little* in front of it seals the deal for uncountability. (And uncountable nouns in this construction seem to require a *that*-clause.)

Comment: @TinfoilHat Are you suggesting that countability has anything to do with the acceptability of the _to be_ deletion?

Comment: Yes. \**There seems a problem* doesn't work. *There seems doubt that...* works. \**There seems an issue* doesn't work. *There seems reason to...* works.

Comment: There are at least three syntactic rules interacting here: Raising, _There_-Insertion, and _To Be_-Deletion. They are in complex feeding orders. Which ones are you asking about?

Comment: @JohnLawler Whatever syntactic rules you feel are necessary to answer the question.

Comment: Once again, I'm wanting to see exactly what the question is that you want an answer to. I see a number of questions I could answer, but I have no sense of the overall question. Perhaps I should ask whether you understand what a derivation is, because that's what I'd hafta do and I'd rather not hafta explain each step.

Comment: @JohnLawler The question is about the existential construction "There seem(s) to be + [displaced subject]". And I'd like to know when it's better to omit "to be" and when it's better to keep it. I think Tinfoil Hat is on to something.

Comment: Couldn't tell you "when"; it'll be here and there, depending on how the rules interact and what the verbs are. And it's not a single construction. And there are 4 sentences as data.

Comment: [It seems (to be) a](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It+seems+to+be+a%2CIt+seems+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows the opposite pattern, oddly enough, with "it seems a" more common.

Comment: @alphabet Welcome to English grammar :)

Comment: The question presupposes that locutions of this sort follow a consistent pattern.  Does there have to be a reason for a difference  of this kind?  Why can it not be down to chance (that and the more general inconsistency of the English language?

Answer (score 0):

The verb "to seem" is normally followed by an adjective. "It seems problematic". In the original example, the whole expression "there seems to be a problem", the "to be" is only obligatory because of the presence of "there", their combination giving the notion of existence. "There is a problem = A problem exists". So the deletion of "to be".

The uncountability (measurability) of "doubt" has nothing to do with it nor is it as strict, after all, as to forbid a sentence as "There is no doubt".
"It seems doubtful". "There seems to be some/no doubt".

Comment: But 'there seems some doubt about' (it seems that some doubt exists about) is available as well as 'there seems to be some doubt about', so ' "to be" is only obligatory because of the presence of "there", their combination giving the notion of existence' doesn't hold water, I'm afraid, Maria.

Comment: Edwin Ashworth: I am really not familiar with this version ("there seems some doubt"). I may not be a native English speaker, but I think that, even if available, it is not used enough as to be accepted as grammatical. Having done some more research after your comment, I only found the existential "there" combined either with "to be" or with presentational verbs.

Comment: [Ludwig](https://ludwig.guru/s/there+seems+some) provides examples from the New Yorker etc. But this area certainly involves _divided usage_; I find some of their other examples (eg 'Still, there seems some leakage') unacceptable. But Science, English Romantic Opera, Michael Palin, The Guardian, Thomson Reuters, Ofgem, the BMJ, the Science Media Centre, YouGov/Sunday Times, the Scottish Legal Aid Board, and Old Marston Parish Council are all happy to use 'There seems some doubt [about etc] ...'.

Comment: Thank you. Facing all these, I stand corrected regarding the extent of use of the personal "seem". (And yet, if it's an equally valid variation, how come it is so often objected to?).

Comment: Greenwald and Svartvik, I believe, investigated the meta-question of 'what does "acceptable" actually mean?' They found that practised linguists couldn't agree on the acceptability of some sentences. They introduced a gradience (Likert-like) model ( [C]:'60% ... acceptable' (ie say 6 out of 10 post-grad English students judge sentence 23 to be acceptable).